# Cannot use table 'AspNetUsers' in schema '' for entity 'AspNetUsers' since it is being used for another entity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

We are trying to add Identity 3 to our existing Customers app by extending AspNetUsers

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Countries Country { get; set; }
    public string AddressLabel { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FollowUp { get; set; }
    public bool MailingList { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubscriptionId")]
    public virtual Subscriptions Subscription { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Devices> Devices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Downloads> Downloads { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invoices> Invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Referrals> Referrals { get; set; }
}
```

CustomersContext inherits from IdentityDbContext

```
    public partial class CustomersContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Customers;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);// we have to do this becauee we are inheriting from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> not DbContext
        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoleClaims>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Role).WithMany(p => p.AspNetRoleClaims).HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedName).HasName("RoleNameIndex");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedName).HasMaxLength(256);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserClaims>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserClaims).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });

            entity.Property(e => e.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.Property(e => e.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserLogins).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRoles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Role).WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserRoles).HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserRoles).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.BusinessName).HasName("BusinessNameIndex");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasName("EmailIndex");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasName("UserNameIndex");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.Property(e => e.AddressLabel)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.BusinessName)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.ContactName)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryCode)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasDefaultValue("00");

            entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.Property(e => e.FollowUp).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.MailingList).HasDefaultValue(true);

            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Country).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(d => d.CountryCode).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Subscription).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(d => d.SubscriptionId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Countries>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.CountryCode);

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryCode)
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.CalCost).HasColumnType("decimal");

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.CultureCode)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(8)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.CurrencyCode)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(3)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceFooter)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.TaxName)
                .HasMaxLength(3)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.TaxRate).HasColumnType("decimal");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Devices>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DeviceID);

            entity.Property(e => e.CALs).HasDefaultValue(0);

            entity.Property(e => e.DeviceName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.UnlockedFrom).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.UnlockedTo).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Devices).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Downloads>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DownloadId);

            entity.Property(e => e.DownloadDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.DownloadVersion)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Downloads).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoices>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.InvoiceNr);

            entity.Property(e => e.AddressLabel)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceDescription)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceNet).HasColumnType("money");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceTax).HasColumnType("money");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceTotal).HasColumnType("money");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Invoices).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Notes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.NoteId);

            entity.Property(e => e.NoteDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.NoteSubject)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.NoteText)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Notes).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ReferralSources>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.ReferralSourceId);

            entity.Property(e => e.ReferralSourceName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Referrals>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.ReferralId);

            entity.Property(e => e.ReferralDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.ReferralSource).WithMany(p => p.Referrals).HasForeignKey(d => d.ReferralSourceID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Referrals).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Subscriptions>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.SubscriptionId);

            entity.Property(e => e.SubscriberId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.Property(e => e.SubscriptionExpires).HasColumnType("date");
            entity.Property(e => e.TotalCALs).HasDefaultValue(0);

        });
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Countries> Countries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Devices> Devices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Downloads> Downloads { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Invoices> Invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ReferralSources> ReferralSources { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Referrals> Referrals { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Subscriptions> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

We are trying to use Microsoft authentication. When I run the app and login using Microsoft Account then the app blows up in the `AccountController` `ExternalLoginCallback` on this line

```
 var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
```

The error is

```
Cannot use table 'AspNetUsers' in schema '' for entity 'AspNetUsers' since it is being used for another entity.
```

There is no other dbContext other than CustomersContext. I can't find any entities mapping to AspNetUsers other than ApplicationUser.

There are no migrations. The same error also occurs if I try to create an initial migration.

```
dnx ef migrations add initial
```

Apologies for the amount of code included and yet not including that critical piece of information whatever it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you inherit from `IdentityDbContext`, you don't need to recreate `AspNet*` DbSet, just add your new table.
Your CustomersContext should look like that:

```
public partial class CustomersContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Customers;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);// we have to do this because we are inheriting from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> not DbContext

        // override the users tables with your properties
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.BusinessName).HasName("BusinessNameIndex");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasName("EmailIndex");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasName("UserNameIndex");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.Property(e => e.AddressLabel)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.BusinessName)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.ContactName)
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryCode)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasDefaultValue("00");

            entity.Property(e => e.FollowUp).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.MailingList).HasDefaultValue(true);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Country).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(d => d.CountryCode).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Subscription).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(d => d.SubscriptionId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Countries>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.CountryCode);

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryCode)
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.CalCost).HasColumnType("decimal");

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.CultureCode)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(8)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.CurrencyCode)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(3)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceFooter)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.TaxName)
                .HasMaxLength(3)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.TaxRate).HasColumnType("decimal");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Devices>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DeviceID);

            entity.Property(e => e.CALs).HasDefaultValue(0);

            entity.Property(e => e.DeviceName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.UnlockedFrom).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.UnlockedTo).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Devices).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Downloads>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DownloadId);

            entity.Property(e => e.DownloadDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.DownloadVersion)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Downloads).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoices>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.InvoiceNr);

            entity.Property(e => e.AddressLabel)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceDescription)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceNet).HasColumnType("money");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceTax).HasColumnType("money");

            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceTotal).HasColumnType("money");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Invoices).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Notes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.NoteId);

            entity.Property(e => e.NoteDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.NoteSubject)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.NoteText)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Notes).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ReferralSources>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.ReferralSourceId);

            entity.Property(e => e.ReferralSourceName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Referrals>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.ReferralId);

            entity.Property(e => e.ReferralDate).HasColumnType("date");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.ReferralSource).WithMany(p => p.Referrals).HasForeignKey(d => d.ReferralSourceID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Referrals).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Subscriptions>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.SubscriptionId);

            entity.Property(e => e.SubscriberId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.Property(e => e.SubscriptionExpires).HasColumnType("date");
            entity.Property(e => e.TotalCALs).HasDefaultValue(0);

        });
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Countries> Countries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Devices> Devices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Downloads> Downloads { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Invoices> Invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ReferralSources> ReferralSources { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Referrals> Referrals { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Subscriptions> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can completely create the model without calling  `base.OnModelCreating`, you can copy the `OnModelCreating` [from the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/89a9acea96d2cdd8d4c1e57e8356959114bc7eb6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs)

Comment: Thank you @agua from mars. I have deleted AspNet* DbSet from CustomersContext as you suggested, however the same error recurs on the same line. The same error also still recurs when running    'dnx ef database update -c CustomersContext'

Comment: My error @agua from mars. I did not delete all AspNet* DbSet from CustomersContext. Now I have and it works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from the same problem using the following scenario:

1. Scaffolding identity (code first)
2. Update the same DB with identity tables using migrations (code first)
3. Scaffold the DB context from the database. (db first)

Currently I'm trying to use a separate DB for identity for the following gains:

1. To keep Microsoft identity as a separate module so you can update
   it or remove it easily from your application.
2. To create a single
   sign on architecture between multiple applications.
3. To keep the
   application context flexible for both ways, i.e. DB-first or
   Code-first at any time.

The challenge now is to use the two databases together at the data tier of the application.

Comment: is this an answer?