# "Cannot use table in schema '' for entity since it is being used for another entity" error

Tags: .net

We are trying to map the `ASPNetUsers` table to our custom table users. Below are the classes and their relationship.

```
public partial class Users     
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }       
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }        
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    public string UserInfoId { get; set; }    
    public virtual AspNetUsers UserInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
}
```

When we are implementing the identity using these models, we get the         below error:

> "Cannot use table 'AspNetUsers' in schema '' for entity 'AspNetUsers' since it is being used for another entity."

We have not done any changes in the `ASPNetUsers` tables; it is same as we got through the migration.

How can we fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575020/cannot-use-table-aspnetusers-in-schema-for-entity-aspnetusers-since-it-is)

Answer (score 5):

In your `ApplicationDbContext` you have to customize the `AspNetUsers` table:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    new AspNetUsersConfiguration(builder.Entity<AspNetUsers>());
}
```

And in your Configuration file:

```
public class AspNetUsersConfiguration
{
    public AspNetUsersConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<AspNetUsers> entity)
    {
     entity.ToTable("AspNetUsers", "dbo");
     entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    }
}
```

The key answer is in define a schema `dbo` to table `AspNetUsers`.